# Custom e-mail template shows raw html

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

I created an e-mail template like this:

**email_templates.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../Email/etc/email_templates.xsd">
  <template id="send_email_delivery_confirmation" label="Email Form" file="email_confirmation.html" type="text" module="Namespace_Module" area="frontend"/>
</config>
```

**email_confirmation.html**

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td>Again</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the problem is, when i open the email, the html tag not rendred at all, so it shows the html tag inside the email content:

[image: example]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change file type `type="text"` to `html` in `email_templates.xml`.